# Flexagon Simulation

Tags: math, 3d, 2d, simulation, topology

What is the best way to simulate a flexagon?

My best guess at a starting point is to represent the faces and edges, and simulate transformations based where edges meet. I'm thinking that in the process of implementing a transformation, it will be apparent when folding in a given direction is physically impossible.

I'm going to try to figure this out by experimentation, but it definitely feels like the kind of problem where a gap in my facility with mathematics is holding me back.

Edit: To clarify, I'm interested in what sort of data structures I could use to represent a flexagon and how I can manipulate those data structures to simulate the folding of a flexagon.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in math.stackexchange?

Comment: I chose to post to question on stackoverflow.com because my question is specifically about implementation, i.e. what data structure(s) should I use and what algorithms can I use to manipulate them?

Comment: Have you tried a go at this? I am very interested in seeing some code even if it doesn't work :) because it is a form of recursion as a state machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write all of the invariants of the flexagon as a system of equations, small deviations around legal states may be written as a linear system.  For instance, the stiffness of a piece of paper between `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` enforces

```
(x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 - L**2 == 0
```

This can be be softened to

```
chi2 = (x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 - L**2 + other constraints...
```

Derivatives of `chi2` with respect to `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` yield linear equations.  A system of linear equations is a matrix, and an eigenvalue/eigenvector decomposition of that matrix give you linear combinations of the `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` parameters that are easy or hard to bend.  The eigenvectors are a basis set of possible directions and each one's corresponding eigenvalue tells you how hard it is to bend in that direction.  Larger eigenvalues are more constrained.

A problem with the above is that if there are any directions that are truly allowed, that is, the derivative of `chi2` with respect to `p` is 0 (the original constraint is absolutely satisfied), then the matrix is singular and can't be inverted to get the eigensystem.  If you only want to know what those absolutely allowed directions are, you can compute the null space of the matrix instead of its eigensystem.  However, I suspect (never having played with a flexagon) that the "allowed" directions involve a little bit of bending, in which case `chi2` is small but nonzero.  Then you'd be looking for small but nonzero eigenvalues.  Other degrees of freedom are allowed and uninteresting, such as translation or rotation of the whole object.  To turn it into a pure eigensystem problem (no null space at all), add constraints to the system with arbitrarily small constants lambda:

```
chi2 += lambda_x * (x1 + x2)**2/4.0 + lambda_y * (y1 + y2)**2/4.0
```

You'll recognize them in your solution because they'll vary as you vary each lambda.  (The example above gives a penalty `lambda_x` to translating in x and `lambda_y` to translating in y.)

In terms of implementation, you can use any linear algebra software to compute solutions and check for variation with the lambdas.  I used Python to prototype a problem like this (detector alignment in high energy physics, in which the constraints are measurements like "this detector is 3 cm from that detector" and the `chi2` was derived from the uncertainties "3 cm +- 0.1 cm") and then ported the solution to C++ (BLAS) for production.  The Numpy library for Python had enough linear algebra (it's BLAS under the hood), though I also used the generic, non-linear minimizers in Scipy to debug the matrix solution.  The hardest part is getting the indexes to line up right, which is necessary when casting it as a matrix and not when you give an objective function to a generic minimizer (because you use variable names instead).  This is more of a Matlab or Mathematica problem, so if you're more comfortable with one of them, use it instead.  This problem will require a lot of trial and error, so use the most *interactive* system possible (one with a good REPL or worksheet/notebook-style interface).

It can also be helpful to draw a graph of the connections (graph-theory graph, not a plot), on which to label their constraints.  For me, that was a necessary first step before writing out the equations.

It might also help to visualize the system by writing a set of functions that take parameter values (`x1`, etc.) and draw the figure with OpenGL (or other 3-D mesh renderer).  This can show you if some constraint is being violated, because the mesh tiles would pass theough each other.  It can also help you identify the degrees of freedom represented by each eigenvector: vary the parameters by the linear combination represented by the eigenvector and you'll see if it's just translating/rotating or if it's doing some interesting twist or fold.

Comment: Word. Thank you. I've accepted the answer as correct, but I'm going to have to take some time to make sure I understand everything. I will definitely report back with the results of my efforts. Thank you for setting me in the right direction!